# C++ AMP iterating over array_views with different dimensions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, gpgpu, c++-amp

I am using C++ AMP with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8. I have a case where I have 2D array_view, `experimentData` and a 1D array_view, `experimentFactors`. I want to iterate over the first dimension of the 2D array_view and the 1 dimension of the 1D array_view. This is what I have but I constantly get errors saying there aren't overloads for this. I am wanting to iterate over the `numberOfTests` which is the first dimension. I am wanting the line:

```
auto test = experimentData[idx];
```

to return the entire row of data. I think the `section` method on the `array_view` is the way to do this but I can't figure out how.

```
array_view<int_2, 2> experimentData(numberOfTests, numberOfSolutions, initialConditionSet);
array_view<float_2, 1> experimentFactors(numberOfTests, factorData);
extent<1> e_size(numberOfTests);

parallel_for_each(e_size, [=] (index<1> idx) restrict(amp) {
    auto test = experimentData.section(idx);
    auto factors = experimentFactors[idx];

    analysisAlgorithm(test, factors);
});
```

The `test` object should be a 1xN section of the `experimentData` `array_view`. The `factors` object should be a single item from the `experimentFactors` `array_view`.

**Clarification**

The `experimentData` array_view has M rows and N columns

The `experimentFactors` array_view has M rows

Comment: What are the sizes of each? Is it MxN and M, or MxN and M*N?

Comment: experimentData is MxN, experimentFactors is M

Comment: Why extract the entire line from the matrix? Why not loop over it instead?

Comment: I use the entire row in the kernel code which is not shown. I don't work on the individual members. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are someone working on C++ and you have questions like this one or with dealing projecting data to different dimensions stop and read this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2012/02/17/projections-in-c-amp.aspx

It deals with this exact problem in a beautiful way. Here is what my parallel_for loop looks like now:

```
parallel_for_each(e_size, [=] (index<1> idx) restrict(amp) {
    array_view<int_2, 1> test = experimentData[idx[0]];
    auto factors = experimentFactors[idx];

    analysisAlgorithm(test, factors);
});
```

Notice how the creation of the `test` array has changed. I state that it is going to be a 1D array of type `int_2`. Then I use the projection technique discussed in the article to select the entire row of data with `= experimentData[idx[0]];`. When you only give one index to a multidimensional array it selects all of the data held within that dimension. The article makes this clearer.